# How can I change CSS modules in CRA?

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, css-modules

I use a hyphenated naming convention in my CSS and CRA's out-of-the-box CSS Modules doesn't convert that to camelCase in the JS files. This forces me to use bracket syntax, e.g., `styles["my-class"]`, which is awful. `className={styles.myClass}` is a lot more readable and easier to use.

Is there a way to change this without ejecting or using `react-app-rewired`? I don't care for camel-casing in my CSS, but it's my last resort.

Answer (score -1):

There is an [option for this within css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#exportlocalsconvention) but you can't get to it without using one of the libraries for extending CRA config or ejecting.